# How to change text inside 'value' attribute of option(select)?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id="selectnav1" class="selectnav">
<option value="">- Navigation -</option>
<option selected="" value="javascript:void">Category 1</option>
<option value="javascript:void">Airbrush tanning</option>
<option value="javascript:void">Category 3</option>
<option value="javascript:void">Category 4</option>
<option value="javascript:void">Category 5</option>
<option value="javascript:void">Category 6</option>
</select>
```

I want to replace/set the text inside value attribute with the main text inside option element. Example: for first option i.e. categeory 1, i want to chnge javascript:void to 'category 1' and same applies to all other options.

### [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cilay/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: try my updated ans to skip the first option value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#selectnav1 > option:gt(0)').val(function(){
    return $(this).text();
});
```

`gt` selector means greater than the index.

Comment: Indeed, it worked. Can i skip the first option i.e. navigation?

Comment: @Orahmax, Try with `$('#selectnav1 > option:gt(0)').val.....` Here used https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: @Orahmax, sorry, I didn't see the comment. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, you can skip any option value

```
$('#selectnav1 > option').each(function(i, o){
    if(i > 0)
      o.value = o.text;
});
```

Comment: this worked too!. Now i am confused, which one to select as best answer?

Comment: @Orahmax, i is key of option object, you can skip any option by the `IF` condition..

Comment: @Orahmax, Don't get confused selected which helped you the most, irrespective of who gave the answer or upvotes.

Comment: @Girish, `i` is __index__ and a suggestion always use correct and proper names `function(index, Element)` avoid using `a, e` as variable name

Comment: @Satpal, both are same things.. thanks for your suggestion. but sort code is better

Comment: @Girish Rember objective of SO is not only for OP but also for future user who visit the page and sees your answer will they identify that `i` is `index` and `o` is `element`, if they are not familiar with each

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('#selectnav1 > option').val(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $('#selectnav1 option').each(function() {

            $(this).val($(this).text());
        });
```